# Calling DLL file from the Java code

Tags: java, c#, dll

I am trying to call a DLL file from the Java code. I have set the system property for the library path. Also I have set the Java library path. But I am not able to access the DLL file. I have given the DLL file and set the property using library path. I have also called the `loadLibrary` module and then called the DLL file. But I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Can someone please elaborate why I am getting this problem ?

Comment: Is that the whole error?

Comment: Is both the dll and JVM using the same bit depthness (x64 or x32)

Comment: Thank for your response. I am getting the following error:

Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:. Also I am running this from ubuntu eclipse machine. Is it compatible. Is there any machine that can be compatible for running the code ?

Comment: A little code would be nice... are you passing "foo.dll" as a parameter? Or, just "foo"? Can you confirm the library you are searching for exists?.. please clarify.

Comment: How C# tag is related to the question?

Comment: The code is compiled from .NET dll. So I tagged C#.
I have to call from java and run the method in the dll using JNI.
Using java.library.path, I have set the path.
Then for the file foo.dll, I called like this.
Then using System.loadLibrary("foo").

Comment: I am able to load the library. But when I called the method in the .NET dll code, I am getting the following error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ClassDll.XYZ(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; 
The input argument to the method is String and return type is also string.So I declared method like this in java code.
public native String XYZ(String arg1);
XYZ is a function which is written in .NET in the class called ClassDll. 
Then using java object I called function in the dll. Can you please tell me pass String variable from java to dll function? Is it possible.